# validation using javascript in visual studio on an aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

The email id is entered into a textbox and the validation for email is applied but there seems to be an error that the whole function is probably not called during execution

```
  <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function IsValidUrl()
             {
                 var emailbox = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox4.Text %>');<!--textbox4 is used to receive the email entered by the user-->
                 var email = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
                 if (textbox.value.length > 0)<!--the email field should be non empty-->
                 {
                     if (email.test(emailbox.value))
                     {
                         return true;
                     }
                     else
                     {

                         alert("Please enter valid Email");<!--incase of an invalid email-->
                         return false;
                     }

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     alert("please enter text");
                     return false;
                 }


             }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 340px" Text="Submit" Width="96px" OnClick="Button1_Click1" OnClientClick="javascript:IsValidUrl();"/>
      </form>
    </body>``
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your function is working correctly but the page gets submitted even after the validation so replace below:

```
OnClientClick="javascript:IsValidUrl();"
```

with

```
OnClientClick="return javascript:IsValidUrl();"
```

**Edit**

Just figured an error in your JS code `if (textbox.value.length > 0)` line should be  `if (emailbox.value.length > 0)` so try with replace it.

Another issue I found in `document.getElementById('<%=TextBox4.Text %>')` which should be `document.getElementById('<%=TextBox4.ID %>')` and in case of using master pages it should be `document.getElementById('<%=TextBox4.ClientID %>')` so try replacing it too.

Hope this will help !!

Comment: @avinoor, it means there is some problem in your javascript method. I figured something, have a look in my updated answer.

Comment: sir it seems that the function is not being called. no alert box appears when an incorrect email is entered int the text box and the email is then ultimately stored inside the database (sql server).

Comment: @avinoor, have a look on my updated answer. I checked your email check regex and its working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/zfeqh6dx/

Comment: sir i believe there is a glitch with the asp button tag in the second last line because the function is not called during execution

Comment: @avinoor, I can't say perfectly as this is just a piece of your entire page code. Try check with browser console if you found any issue out there.

Comment: sir if possible could i send u the entire projrct for u to take a look at

Comment: thanks anyways the correct syntax was textbox4.clientID

Comment: @avinoor, does the problem resolved? I also mentioned in my updated answer that you should use `ClientID` instead of `ID` in case of using in master pages.

Answer (score 0):

There seems couple of issue with the javascript's IsValidURL function so please replace it with below code.

```
function IsValidUrl()
         {
             var emailbox = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox4.ID %>');
             var email = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
             if (emailbox.value.length > 0)
             {
                 if (email.test(emailbox.value))
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
                 else
                 {

                     alert("Please enter valid Email");
                     return false;
                 }

             }
             else
             {
                 alert("please enter text");
                 return false;
             }


         }
```

There are mainly two problems

1. <%=TextBox4.Text %> here you want id of the textBox but you are fetching value of the textBox.
2. textbox.value.length you want to check value of the TextBox4 but its variable name is emailbox, not textbox.
   So I have just corrected those.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: the difference was textbox4.id instead of textbox4.text

Comment: I have edited it and there are mainly two problems which I described.

Comment: i have made the above changes but it still doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Can you please open the Browser console and see if it is showing any error.

And if doesn't show any error then can put a breakpoint in IsValidURL function and debug through browser itself.